2017 1500 Sierra Denali tailgate
One side of my tailgate doesn’t close unless I force it and when it does it is hard to open. One side closes just fine and when only that side is closed it opens just fine but when I force the other side shut its hard to pull on the handle to get it open.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! One side or the other probably needs to be adjusted.

How do I do that?

@Paulster2 do I just adjust the striker bolt?

I believe you need to adjust the strikers (the parts on the sides which the tailgate latches to). While I've never personally done it, I found this very basic step-by-step (from this website):

Remove both taillights.
Loosen striker nuts just enough for the striker to move if you give it a bump.
Pull both strikers towards the rear.
Close the tailgate.
With tailgate closed, tighten striker nuts.

I realize this is for an earlier GM truck, but the process should be the same.

Ok thank you for the help
